# Error in prolog

Tags: prolog

```
lookup([(X,A)|_],X,A).      
lookup([_|L],X,A) :- lookup(L,X,A).

hi(_,t,bool).      
hi(_,f,bool).
hi(g,var(X),Y) :- lookup(g,X,Y).
hi(_,in(X),int).
hi(_,fl(X),real_exp).
hi(g,plus(A,B),int) :- hi(g,A,int),hi(g,B,int),!.
```

I have the above line of code in Prolog which basically **checks the type of a plus operation**.

so when I have the following Query at the terminal:

```
hi([],plus(in(1),in(2)),T).
```

I get the answer as false instead of `T = int`.

what could be the correct line of code in my program ?
I am unable to sort out the error !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used an atom `g` in the rule for **hi/3** where you probably meant to use a variable `G`.

Answer (score 0):

the plus rule is:
hi(**g**,plus(A,B),int) :- hi(g,A,int),hi(g,B,int),!.

while you call:
hi(**[]**,plus(in(1),in(2)),T).

not sure what do you want to do with g and [] (some token list perhaps?) but it looks like you have to either change the query or the rule (or and one more rule). maybe g was supposed to be a variable G? cant really tell xd